# How to find Post_ID which related to <AD_SET_ID> Facebook ADS API

Tags: python, facebook, api, ads

I use Python Facebook Ads API.
I got AD_SET_ID.
How Can I find boosted post ID (looks like 204807582871020_615180368500404) which is related to AD_SET_ID

Comment: Solve is:
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/602845**19298/?fields=object_story_id
result:
{
  "object_story_id": "267960943378082_492753974232110",
  "id": "6028456819298"
}

Is There any way to do backwards? If I have POST_ID(267960943378082_492753974232110) Can I get AdSetID or AdCreative if it is exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the post that is used for a creative by fetching the `object_story_id` field on an Ad Creative.
In the hierarchy of Facebook ads products, this is located here: Ad Account -> Ad Campaign -> Ad Set -> Ad -> Ad Creative.

There is no way to reversely look up which ads objects are using a particular post for their creative.